# how do i get react native to play multiple local files

Tags: javascript, ios, css, react-native, video

**i want to play multiple videos and i have this set up but the videos wont show i don't know if i have to add the path or am i just adding everything wrong from const i basically know how to play one video buy adding it to the souce  but i want to play more but i don't know how to import them from a local file?
any suggestions would help thanks in advance**

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions,ImageBackground,ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo';
import { MaterialIcons, Octicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const VIDEOS = [   // replace these links with links to your videos
  './spiderman.mp4',
  'C:\Windows\System32\avengerproject2\spiderman.mp4',
  'C:\Windows\System32\avengerproject2\spiderman.mp4'
  ]


export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        currentVideo: 0,
      mute: false,
      shouldPlay: true,
    }
    handlePlayAndPause = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            shouldPlay: !prevState.shouldPlay
        }));
    }
    handleVolume = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            mute: !prevState.mute,
        }));
  }

  forwardButton = () => {
    if (this.state.currentVideo != VIDEOS.length-1) {
       this.setState({currentVideo: this.state.currentVideo + 1});
    } else {
       this.setState({currentVideo: 0});
    }
 }
 backButton = () => {
    if (this.state.currentVideo != 0) {
       this.setState({currentVideo: this.state.currentVideo - 1});
    } else {
       this.setState({currentVideo: VIDEOS.length-1});
    }
 }
 render() {
  const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
  source={{uri:'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/aqm17QD.jpg'}}
    style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
         <View >
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18, 
                fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Welcome spiderman</Text>
            <Video  source =
              {{uri: VIDEOS[this.state.currentVideo]}}
              shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
              resizeMode="cover"
              style={{ width, height: 300 }}
              isMuted={this.state.mute}
            />
         <View style={styles.controlBar}>
           <MaterialIcons
             name={this.state.mute ? "volume-mute" : 
                  "volume-up"}
             size={45}
             color="white"
             onPress={this.handleVolume}
           />
           <MaterialIcons
             name={this.state.shouldPlay ? "pause" : 
                  "play-arrow"}
             size={45}
             color="white"
             onPress={this.handlePlayAndPause}
           />
        </View>
     </View>
     <View style={{flex: .25, flexDirection: 'row', 
          alignItems: 'center'}}>
       <MaterialIcons
          name={"navigate-before"}
          size={150}
          color="white"
          onPress={this.backButton}
       />
       <Text>Next Video</Text>
       <MaterialIcons
          name={"navigate-next"}
          size={150}
          color="white"
          onPress={this.forwardButton}
       />
    </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);
}
}


 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#B32E2E',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    controlBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
        height: 45,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like you are unable to access to your video files. (Not sure about rest of your code also)

If you want to access any type of asset in your app, you have 2 choices.

**1) Stream video from a server.**

Which would allow you to just add a link of the video like you do with your local mp4 files. (https://videostoragesite.com/spiderman.mp4)

**2) Add assets to your bundle.**

Which you can do with Expo's asset manager, or eject your project to a vanilla react native project and bundle the mp4 files into your app using Xcode or Android Studio.

Comment: How do i access multiple videos